# how to delete from a data table bound a data list control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a data list control that I populate with a datatable that I have created int the code behind. I need to be able to delete a record from the data table by the users selecting the items from the drop datalist. I have a link button control in the  datalist and I also have an Label that stores and ID for the row in the data table. How would I go about doing this?

```
       ` DataTable dt;
        if (ViewState["CurrentData2"] != null)
        {
            dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentData2"];
        }
        else
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Sort Order", typeof(Int64));
            dt.Columns.Add("Task Number", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add("Client Name", typeof(String));

            dt.Columns.Add("Amount Due", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Columns.Add("Change", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Columns.Add("Receipt Amount", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Columns.Add("Receipt Number", typeof(string));

            //**Update**/
            ViewState["CurrentData2"] = dt;


     protected void dl_COD_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         DataTable dt = GetDataTable2();

        for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
            if (dt.Rows[i]["Task Number"].ToString() == dl_COD.Items[1].Controls.ToString())
                dt.Rows.Remove(dr);
            // i--;
        }
        BindGrid();
        if (dt.Rows.Count <= 0)
        {
            mv_BulkUpdate.ActiveViewIndex = -1;
        }
    }
```

`

Comment: You should post your code, because without it is difficult to understand what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2):

Your question is quite hard to understand without a code example, however what I believe you're getting at is `<asp:SqlDataSource>` which allows for you to delete from the list and database using the ID within the list.

This comes hand in hand with `<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource" DataKeyNames="Id"
            InsertItemPosition="FirstItem" ItemPlaceholderID="lay0" OnItemCommand="ListView1_ItemCommand" AllowPaging="True" EnableViewState="true">` within which you can have various templates to carry out CRUD actions.

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx)

So with the below you're using the connection string specified in your webconfig, the datasource as shown below can be placed in your aspx or cs/vb, I've always found it easier in the aspx.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table]" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="True" DataSourceMode="DataReader"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Table] WHERE Id = @Id;"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Table] ([Title], [Details], VALUES (@Title, @Details)"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table] ORDER BY [Title] DESC"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Table] SET [Title] = @Title, [Details] = @Details WHERE [Id] = @Id ">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Details" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Details" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```